# Rhythmbox plugin conflict

Tags: rhythmbox

when i enable cover art search plugin and browse cover art plugin a message appears saying conflicting plugins.Is there a way to enable all plugins
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peeking underneath that dialog you'll notice that you have enabled the coverart-browser plugin.

From *my* [project web-page](https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser) you'll notice in the README that the plugin coverart-search-providers is also a prerequisite for coverart-browser.

So what is coverart-search-providers?

Well, as my other [project web-page](https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-search-providers) also goes onto explain, this plugin is a...

> Drop in Rhythmbox replacement for the default CoverArt Search plugin
>   to provide new and updated coverart search providers both local and by
>   internet image hosts

Thus, you cannot - by design - have both the default cover art search plugin and the coverart-search-providers plugin enabled.

Here is a nice screen-shot that shows coverart-search-providers - you'll notice that you have various local search and internet search providers.

[image: configure]

You are in complete control of how rhythmbox searches for its album art.  The default cover art search plugin does not have this flexibility.

For more information about how to use coverart-search-providers to its fullest potential, look at the linked projects wiki page:

- https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser/wiki/How-to-find-great-coverart

---

If you want to continue using the default cover art search plugin, you need to untick the coverart-search-providers plugin.  This will also untick the coverart-browser plugin as well i.e. you cannot (by design) use coverart-browser with the cover art search plugin.